# Can TTFB be affected after page load?

Tags: html, performance, newrelic, sre

In case of server side rendering, we know that TTFB is the time it takes between the start of the request and the start of the response. My question is can the TTFB be affected if the page visually updates due to filters or something but is not a full page load and the URL is the same as well.

How is TTFB measured when only some of the page resources are requested

Answer (score 0):

no.

time to first byte is how long between the request is sent and the first byte of the response arrives, once the page loads, the first byte, or in fact, presumably ALL the bytes have arrived

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you have a SPA page load, and lets say there is a search bar that would get you new results without reloading the entire page. What would be the TTFB then? Would it change?

Comment: no, that would fire off a second request for the AJAX data, which would have it's own TTFB